# Problema con cyberpanel error 503

Tags: server, vps

primero que nada soy medio nuevo en el uso de vps, contraté uno con hostinger, tiene instalado cyberpanel y el sistema operativo es almalinux.

Estoy teniendo un error cuando quiero previsualizar mi sitio desde el manejador del sitio, ni siquiera me muestra el `index.html` que viene por defecto en `public_html`. y cuando entro a al dominio directamente se queda cargando.

El dominio lo compre en nic.ar y lo configure desde ahí.

Probé de dos maneras una poniendo las `ns1.misitio.com.ar ns2.misitio.com.ar` y la otra agregándole a estas la dirección ip de mi cyberpanel.

En la segunda opción se propaga en `dnstraker` en la primera no.
Alguna sugerencia, si necesitan mas info solo pídanla.

[image: Error que me muestra]